# SSO with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, single-sign-on

I have two Symfony2 application which are using the same database, but hosted on different domains.

Since they are under the same database, I can login with the same Username and Password in both applications.

I want to make the following behaviour:
When someone logins to application1, it automatically logs in to application2 as well.

When I login to application1, a PHPSESSID cookie is created with my logged in session.
However, when I setup the same PHPSESSID cookie under application2, it doesn't log me in.

How can I make both application login at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

create status column in TABLE. set to 1 when user logged in from any application.

STATUS TINYINT(1) NOT NULL // values may 1-active / 0 -not

when it is active don't compare the login condition, directly allow that user with the required session variables.

SESSION may not be available to from one application to another.